# Type "user?" had no member UID (Swift 3, Firebase)

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

I am setting up a login page with Firebase and I've run into an error where `uid` isn't getting recognized. Here's my code:

```
    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (FIRUser,error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return

        }

        guard let uid = user?.uid else {
            return
        }
```

I also can't command-click into `FIRUser`, however if I get rid of the guard statement, authentication works perfectly fine.

I have Firebase and FirebaseDatabase imported (can't import FirebaseAuth, it's crossed out), so it's not that.

Any idea why I can't access `FIRUser` and use `uid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the variable `user` inside your closure. Rewrite your function to this instead.

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user: FIRUser?, error: Error?) in

    if error != nil {
        print(error)
        return

    }

    guard let uid = user?.uid else {
        return
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Emil! Alternatively, can I simply switch the guard statement to use FIRUser instead of user? Doing that works, but as a beginner I'm not sure if I'm messing something else dup by doing it that way instead of yours. Thanks again!

Comment: @d0xi45 `user` is already of type `FIRUser` as shown in my updated answer. When you write it as `(user, error)` instead of my answer, you're simply choosing not to specify the types of the variables. It like doing `var x: Int = 5` or `var x = 5`. They both will be of type `Int` but its one's coding style. Once the creation is completed, `FIRUser.currentUser` is updated as well. The difference is that `user` is a local variable and `FIRUser.currentUser` is global hence accessible anywhere within your app.

Please don't forget to accept and upvote answer if it helped resolve your issue :)